# dynamically adding text from returned data into a div with matching id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

Firstly I am pretty much still a novice and still pretty much still learning, I have already learnt a lot and expect it to continue as I continue this journey. 
Ok so I have the following code and am trying to append the Array Object to the Correct Div with matching ID. I have tried an if statement which does not work and then a Switch statement also no luck. Can anyone pint me in the right direction the comments text must append to the matching divs with same id's.

HTML Divs

```
<div class="containerA" id='text b'></div>

<div class="containerA" id='text a'></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var myArray = [
  a = {
     text: 'text a',
     comment: 'comment a'
      },
  b = {
     text: 'text b',
     comment: 'comment b'
      },
  c = {
     text: 'text a',
     comment: 'comment c'
      },
  d = {
     text: 'text a',
     comment: 'comment d'
      },
  e = {
     text: 'text b',
     comment: 'comment e'
      }
       ];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    var row = myArray[i];
    console.log(row.text);
    var textRef = row.text;
    var commentsText = row.comment;
    console.log(commentsText);
    }

var myContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('containerA');

for (var i = 0; i < myContainer.length; i++) {
    console.log(myContainer[i].attributes[1].nodeValue);
    var idRef = myContainer[i].attributes[1].nodeValue;
    }
```

Comment: You should never use space inside the `id` field

Comment: why not use DOM manipulate of jquey, and not use space in classname

Comment: Thanks I will change that in the returned data as the Divs are created dynamically based on entered data.

Comment: With the answers provided, you no longer need your second for loop. But just wanted to let you know that instead of `myContainer[i].attributes[1].nodeValue` you can just use `myContainer[i].attributes.id`.

Comment: Many thanks jonofan, I'll remember that much appreciated. And Carsten again many thanks the main project is working now I changed the id's to work without spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
myArray.forEach( function(item){
           document.getElementById( item.text ).innerHTML = item.comment;
    });
```

If the requirement is to append and not provide new text every time:

```
    myArray.forEach( function(item){
           var newestComment = document.createTextNode( item.comment );
           document.getElementById( item.text ).appendChild( newestComment  );
    });
```

Comment: I will give this a try, the data is called from a Azure Table so I would think append is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Your `textRef` is equal to the `id` field, so use `$('#' + textRef)` to grap the `div`, then use `append()` to add the `commentsText` to the div

`$('#' + textRef).append(commentsText + "<br>")`

if you want "only javascript" use the code below:

```
var div = document.getElementById('textRef');

div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + commentsText  + '<br />';
```

```js
var myArray = [
  a = {
     text: 'text_a',
     comment: 'comment a'
      },
  b = {
     text: 'text_b',
     comment: 'comment b'
      },
  c = {
     text: 'text_a',
     comment: 'comment c'
      },
  d = {
     text: 'text_a',
     comment: 'comment d'
      },
  e = {
     text: 'text_b',
     comment: 'comment e'
      }
       ];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var row = myArray[i];
    var textRef = row.text;
    var commentsText = row.comment;
    $('#' + textRef).append(commentsText + "<br>")
    }

var myContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('containerA');

for (var i = 0; i < myContainer.length; i++) {
    var idRef = myContainer[i].attributes[1].nodeValue;
    console.log(idRef)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerA" id='text_b'></div>
<br>
<div class="containerA" id='text_a'></div>
```

Comment: I have added it and get the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" I use Jquery-2-2-4 in my Project.

Comment: Ok I have found the Jquery problem moved the Jquery scripts above my JavaScript ref so it appends now and seems to be working many thanks appreciate the help very much.